# how does this while loop in c programming works?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<4,5)
    {
        printf("loop");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The answer is an infinite loop. I can't understand how two expressions work in while loop without any logical operators.

Comment: The duplicate post explains what the comma operator does. For your particular code it results in `while(5)` which is always true and hence infinete loop.

Comment: @kaylum Ok, I found an "exact" dup ;-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/4389800